# using htaccess how can I specify index.html as the home page with both index.html and index.php on the server?

Tags: .htaccess

As my title says, using htaccess how can I specify index.html as the home page with both index.html and index.php on the server ? I have a regular basic html site on the server and I want to start working on a joomla site which of course uses php. I don't want to redirect the php if I enter in the index.php into the address to allow me to start working on the joomla installation. I just want to automatically go to index.html when the domain name is entered. I hope I'm making sense. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just place all the stuff you want to do with Joomla in a subdirectory ? It won't effect your website unless you use the same database names

Answer (score 0):

You use [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) to specify, which file is shown, when just the directory is requested

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```